# ios integration google drive and dropbox like naukri app

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-drive-api, dropbox-api

I am trying to implement an IOS application. The need of my application is to access the documents(pdf,photo etc) from DropBox & Google drive. I am new in iPhone development ,so i have no idea about access the document from DropBox & Google Drive.

If anybody know please help me . Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the API's that you would need to get started with Dropbox and Google Drive.

1. https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/sdks/ios
2. https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/

Comment: thanks for replaying. can you provide some examples

Comment: Your question is too broad to post an example here. You will have to go through the tutorial. However, please consider marking my answer as correct, if this takes you to the right path.

Comment: The Dropbox API you linked is deprecated and will be shut down soon. Just as a heads up.

Comment: Use this: https://www.dropbox.com/developers - v2

Comment: I agree, but the question is too broad as broad as saying - I want to make iOS app. Will take care of your feedback in future.

Comment: Please don't encourage overly broad questions by posting link-only answers. Instead, vote to close the question as too broad.

Comment: Will take care...I'm also learning

Answer (score 0):

[CloudRail](https://cloudrail.com/unified-cloud-storage-api/) might be an alternative. It allows you to integrate both services via the same API which is pretty simple.